# Is there a way to restart mac without reopen all apps via terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, unix, reboot

I'm familiar with `$ sudo shutdown -r now` but I wonder is there a way to restart without reopen all apps?

Comment: In Linux, I use `$ sudo reboot now`. Hope that it works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work, my apps are still reopening :(

Comment: Close all the apps first from the command-line; then restart.

Comment: As @CJK mentioned, you could write a wrapper script to first close all open applications, then execute a `sudo shutdown -r now`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The standard Reboot UI has the checkbox that could be toggled programmatically:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.loginwindow TALLogoutSavesState -bool false
```

Answer (score 1):

On `macOS Big Sur 11.6.2` running this command on the terminal will permanent disable reopening apps:

```
defaults write -g ApplePersistence -bool no
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).